# What's the best way to trigger an animation from the input of another object?

Tags: unity-game-engine, hololens, mrtk

I'm new to unity and c#.

When i air tap on the left sphere, the plane and the right sphere should appear.

[image]
[image]

I figured that an OnPointerClicked event on the left sphere the animation of the plane and right sphere triggers (with an if/else statement). 
Is this the way to go?
If so, how do i do that?

Or is there an easier method?

Thats the script of the left sphere:
[image]

Answer (score 1):

Read this: [IPointerClickHandler.OnPointerClick](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/EventSystems.IPointerClickHandler.OnPointerClick.html)

You need to implement the interface, i.e. `IPointerClickHandler` in your MonoBehaviour class. When you click on the object in game, it will send a click event to [EventSystem](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/EventSystems.EventSystem.html), which triggers the function body you have in your `OnPointerClick` method.

So as the doc mentioned, also make sure you have an EventSyetem (an empty game object with the script attached, or attach the component to your main camera).

Comment: Thank you, i'll try this when i'm home again. 
But is my approach with the animation the "normal" way to do stuff like that?

Comment: @LeonHomburg Strictly speaking there's no "normal" way to do anything with Unity, many functionalities it wouldn't provide and you have to do your own work. But in some degree, yeah, it's expected to do stuffs like this.

Comment: I tried to use IPointerClickHandler, but i dont know if this works with the air tap of the HoloLens?
So i come across the "Interactable Script" (https://microsoft.github.io/MixedRealityToolkit-Unity/Documentation/README_Interactable.html).



On the MainCamera is the Event System script.
The Interactable Script is on a sphere. 
I put the plane into the interactable script of the sphere und took the function that triggers a animation inside of the plane script.
But neither the different states (default, focus, pressed) nor the OnClick Event is working.
https://imgur.com/kNISO1t
.

Comment: @LeonHomburg You don't need any configuration at all. Create a new sphere -> attach a script that inherits `IPointerClickHandler` and implements `OnPointerClick` -> make sure event system exists -> Done.

Comment: @LeonHomburg There're tons of tutorials & posts about `OnPointerClick` please google first. Also for debug purpose you can put `Debug.Log` in your `OnPointerClick` method.

Comment: Thank you for your help.
I started with unity and c# two weeks ago, thats why i’m lagging many basics and google everything. But the OnPointerClick dont worked with the aritap input on the HoloLens and unfortunately there are not so many tutorials on the current MRTK version for the HoloLens.
So i did everything the wiki descripte for the interactable script but it didn‘t worked.

Comment: @LeonHomburg OK of course for HoloLens you need VR kit. That's a totally different  question. I haven't tried HoloLens though but you should definitely check their doc.